# How to add header in mock HTTPResponse

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, wiremock

```
public HttpResponse mockHttpResponse(int status, Token token) throws Exception {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);
    when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
    when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(status);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = mock(HttpEntity.class);
    when(httpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(httpEntity);
    when(httpEntity.getContentType()).thenReturn(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()),
            new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "100"));
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(token);
    when(httpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(getInputStream(bytes));
    return httpResponse;
}
```

I would like to retrieve **response.containsHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL)**, but every time it is returning **false** in my test case execution. Please suggest how can I add **HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL** as my mocked HttpResponse.

Comment: java.net.http.HttpResponse doesnt have a method containsHeader. Which response type are you referring to here?

Comment: org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created a Mock of HttpResponse (not a spy), it means, whatever methods you call on that mocked object, if it's stub is not defined then it will return default or null.

In your case, since you have not defined the stub httpResponse.containsHeader(..)
it will never go to the internal implemented logic of HttpResponseProxy class i.e

```
public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
    return this.original.containsHeader(name);
  }
```

So unless you say,

```
Mockito.when(httpResponse.containsHeader(CACHE_CONTROL)).thenReturn(true);
```

it will never return true.

Another thing, I would like to mention:

The line

```
when(httpEntity.getContentType()).thenReturn(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()),
            new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "100"));
```

means that if the method 'getContentType' on httpEntity is called two times, then first it will return 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' then it will return 'Cache-Control: 100'

Comment: It worked. Is there any way to get the HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL value from response?